# NullPointerException processing XML configuration for Salesforce Data Loader CLI

Tags: data-loader, data-export, cli

Unfortunately I am unable to get Data Loader CLI (v45.0.0 running on Windows) running properly.

This is the command I am using:

```
process "C:\Users\erik\dataloader\custom" Account
```

Even when I use a very simple `process-conf.xml` file and make sure all defined files are present in the file system, I am getting the following output:

```
2019-03-19 10:58:38,141 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.java:473) - Using built-in logging configuration, no log-conf.xml in C:\Users\erik\dataloader\v45.0.0\bin\configs\log-conf.xml
2019-03-19 10:58:38,158 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.java:475) - The log has been initialized
2019-03-19 10:58:38,175 INFO  [main] process.ProcessConfig getBeanFactory (ProcessConfig.java:104) - Loading process configuration from config file: C:\Users\erik\dataloader\custom\process-conf.xml
2019-03-19 10:58:38,294 INFO  [main] support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:495) - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@6f3b5d16: startup date [Tue Mar 19 10:58:38 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-03-19 10:58:38,362 INFO  [main] xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:315) - Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Users\erik\dataloader\custom\process-conf.xml]
2019-03-19 10:58:38,447 INFO  [main] support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557) - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@29
25bf5b: defining beans [Account]; root of factory hierarchy
2019-03-19 10:58:38,481 ERROR [Account] controller.Controller <init> (Controller.java:125) - Exception happened in initConfig:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.stream(Arrays.java:5614)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.getConfigDirFromArgMap(Controller.java:133)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:123)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.getInstance(Controller.java:269)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:117)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:107)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.java:266)
2019-03-19 10:58:38,498 FATAL [Account] process.ProcessRunner topLevelError (ProcessRunner.java:251) - Unable to run process Account
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.stream(Arrays.java:5614)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.getConfigDirFromArgMap(Controller.java:133)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:123)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.getInstance(Controller.java:269)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:117)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:107)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.java:266)
```

This is my `process-conf.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="Account"
    class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
    singleton="false">
        <description>Export Account Data</description>
        <property name="name" value="Account"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.enableLastRunOutput" value="false"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>
            <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="SELECT Id FROM Account"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="C:\Users\erik\dataloader\custom\extract.csv"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8" value="true" />
        </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

According to the exception the property `salesforce.config.dir` might not be configured correctly but this is not the case - the directory `"C:\Users\erik\dataloader\custom"` is resolved correctly by `process.bat` and the `process-conf.xml` can be read.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the Salesforce endpoint & your credentials.  [This documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_intro.htm) shows how to add them.

Comment: Hi, I had my credentials specified in config.properties. Even when I specify valid credentials within the XML as shown in the documentation - including the encrypted password, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Update: I can reproduce the same error every time I follow the linked tutorial without any customizations. For me this looks like a bug of the current version.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce devs released a fix to the issue.  You can download the updated release from github or wait until 3/25 when available for download via Salesforce.

https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues/179